# can number of Spark task be greater than the executor core?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What happens when number of spark tasks be greater than the executor core? How is this scenario handled by Spark

Comment: number of executor cores?

Comment: I am asking about a scenario were the number of executor core > total number of task

Comment: I will add number of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this related to [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414620/can-the-number-of-executor-cores-be-greater-than-the-total-number-of-spark-tasks)

Anyway, you can check this [Cloudera How-to](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/#:~:text=Every%20Spark%20executor%20in%20an,property%20in%20the%20spark%2Ddefaults.). In "Tuning Resource Allocation" section, It's explained that a spark application can request executors by turning on the dynamic allocation property. It's also important to set cluster properties such as num-executors, executor-cores, executor-memory... so that spark requests fit into what your resource manager has available.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is a little off beam. It is unlikely what you ask. Why?

- With a lot of data you will have many partitions and you may repartition.
- Say you have 10,000 partitions which equates to 10,000 tasks.
- An executor (core) will serve a partition effectively a task (1:1 mapping) and when finished move on to the next task, until all tasks finished in the stage and then next will start (if it is in plan / DAG).
- It's more likely you will not have a cluster of 10,000 executor cores at most places (for your App), but there are sites that have that, that is true.
- If you have more cores allocated than needed, then they remain idle and non-usable for others. But with dynamic resource allocation, executors can be relinquished. I have worked with YARN and Spark Standalone, how this is with K8 I am not sure.
- Transformations alter what you need in terms of resources. E.g. an order by may result in less partitions and thus may contribute to idleness.

Answer (score 2):

yes, this scenario can happen. In this case some of the cores will be idle. Scenarios where this can happen:

- You call `coalesce` or `repartition` with a number of partitions < number of cores
- you use the default number of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (=200)
  and you have more than 200 cores available. This will be an issue for
  joins, sorting and aggregation. In this case you may want to increase `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`

Note that even if you have enough tasks, some (or most) of them could be empty. This can happen if you have a large data skew or you do something like `groupBy()` or `Window` without a `partitionBy`. In this case empty partitions will be finished immediately, turning most of your cores idle